# Does "clear:right" affect left floated elements?

Tags: html, css, css-float

Imagine I have the following markup:

```
<div class="right">Box right 1</div>
<div class="right">Box right 2</div>
<div class="left">Box left</div>

<p>... long text ...</p>
```

and the following CSS:

```
.right { float:right; clear: right; }
.left { float:left; clear: left; }

div { /* some styles for the divs */ }
```

This will result in the following (see [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uTRAr/1/)):

[image: result]

This is not the result I expected. I thought the left box is also floated on the top like here:

[image: expected result]

**Question:** Why is the left box not floated on the top? The text inside `<p>` begins on top although its written after the left box in the markup. So I would expect, that also `div.left` starts on top.

**Note:** After deleting `clear: right` in the CSS of the class `.right` the left box is top floated (see [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uTRAr/3/)):

[image: after deleting clear:right]

So it seems, that `clear:right` has a effect on left-floating elements...?!

**Note 2:** Also this markup would float the boxes as expected ([jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uTRAr/4/)):

```
<div class="right">Box right 1</div>
<div class="left">Box left</div>
<div class="right">Box right 2</div>

<p>... long text ...</p>
```

Comment: Float left elements should be *before* float right elements.  Float right elements should be *after* non-float elements that they are intended to "float" to the right of.  So - no, clear right does not.  But, the float right elements before the float left element affect the float left element.

Comment: @cale_b: I get the same effect with two left floated boxes and a right floated box (although I define them in the ordering you mention). http://jsfiddle.net/uTRAr/6/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you may have suspected, `clear: right` will only clear right floats, not left floats. The left float is not being affected by clearance — at least, not directly. It's actually obeying rule #5 in the following list from the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#float-position):

> Here are the precise rules that govern the behavior of floats:
>
> [...]
>
> 5. The outer top of a floating box may not be higher than the outer top of any block or floated box generated by an element earlier in the source document.

This is because clearance is designed to only affect floats that come *before* an element in the source.

Since the second right float is clearing the first one, it sits underneath the first one. And since the left float comes after both of them in the source, it cannot float any higher than the second float because of the clearance that affects the second float.

If you move the left float all the way to the top in the source:

```
<div class="left">Box left</div>
<div class="right">Box right 1</div>
<div class="right">Box right 2</div>

<p>... long text ...</p>
```

You'll see [the same expected behavior](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/uTRAr/7). This is where the difference between `clear: right` and `clear: left`/`both` becomes significant. If the boxes were made to clear in both directions, only then will the left float be cleared by both the right floats.